# Coding non linear regression, Exponential decay

Tags: r, non-linear-regression, nls

Still a novice with R.

Background

I have the data from Li et al. 2003 paper "Belowground biomass dynamics in the Carbon Budget Model of the Canadian Forest Sector".(https://cdnsciencepub.com/doi/10.1139/x02-165) I am trying to recreate equation 6 in R so that I can produce the same parameter estimates. (eq. 6), however, Pf has a maximum value of 0.426, as values greater will produce a 0.

To impose a maximum for the function we can impose limits on the parameters. The easiest is if I can reparameterize the function in terms of the maximum. In the case that RB>0 and the exponential term is decaying, we have for the function Pf(RB)=a+bexp(cRB) the maximum

> m = max(Pf) = a+b

So this could be rewritten as

> a = m − b

and fit the equation

> Pf(RB) = m − b + b·exp(c·RB) = m(1 − b·exp(c·RB))

I would like to code this using nls in r but I don't know how I would go about doing this with the upper limit. I am trying to produce the model in R so I can get the same parameters generated in table 3 equation number 6. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Any chance you can post the data or a link to it?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1A6Jkm-zHb6pE7QeLvCmFF3_l70xJ9wiEFsQHiijUVPA/edit?usp=sharing Does this work?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1A6Jkm-zHb6pE7QeLvCmFF3_l70xJ9wiEFsQHiijUVPA/edit?usp=sharing this link might be better if anyone else wants to look at the data.

Comment: from your last equation, wouldn't `m − b + bexp(cRB) = m - b(1 − exp(cRB))` (instead of `m(1 − bexp(cRB))`)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `nls` as follows.

```
fit = nls(fine_prop ~ m * (1 - b * exp(c*total_root)),
    data = fr,
    start = list(m=0.1, b = 2, c=-0.05))

coefficients(fit)
#          m           b           c 
# 0.06851410 -5.06265496 -0.05369425 

plot(fr)
x = seq(0, max(fr$total_root), length.out=100)
lines(x, predict(fit, newdata = data.frame(total_root = x)))
```

[image]

Equivalently, we can also put the equation in the same format as in the published article, rather than the form in OP.  The we have:

```
fit = nls(fine_prop ~ a + b * exp(c*total_root),
    data = fr,
    start = list(a=1, b = 1, c=-0.1))

coefficients(fit)
#          a          b          c 
#  0.0685124  0.3468601 -0.0536925
```

The data:

```
fr = structure(list(total_root = c(28, 47.5, 104.5, 62, 59.8304, 50.9335, 
40.1412, 43.3121, 131.0057, 24.74, 137.71, 25.004, 88.1, 88.1, 
57.6, 57.6, 54.16, 82.82, 88.6, 134.68, 20.92, 25.004, 141.31, 
143.8, 204.04, 104.88, 172.8, 122.62, 157.7, 18.184, 13.538, 
10.4, 27, 36.7, 44.2, 53.9, 78.6, 47.5, 6.6, 10.1, 14.6, 16.8, 
18.3, 8, 9.5, 6.2, 14.1, 15.8, 21.6, 29.1, 33.2, 41, 45, 46, 
59, 37.6, 9.3, 15, 22.7, 43.2, 37.1, 51, 28.6, 60, 75.2, 12.2, 
43.8, 43.3, 6.8, 6, 7.1, 8.9, 94.3, 100.5, 44.9, 9.98, 9.17, 
7.38, 20.9, 9.6, 11.48, 22.68, 27.63, 27.63, 15.19, 27.78, 26.63, 
12.44, 16.7, 0.5, 3.13), fine_prop = c(0.033796, 0.037486, 0.033818, 
0.033774, 0.10147, 0.032788, 0.068508, 0.045253, 0.005412, 0.373484, 
0.092876, 0.196049, 0.030647, 0.051078, 0.144097, 0.182292, 0.182422, 
0.051195, 0.059594, 0.113306, 0.291587, 0.141337, 0.115562, 0.0758, 
0.053911, 0.075324, 0.075231, 0.08563, 0.061509, 0.125825, 0.130743, 
0.203846, 0.37037, 0.174387, 0.144796, 0.079777, 0.075064, 0.042316, 
0.090909, 0.059406, 0.047945, 0.039881, 0.040984, 0.0875, 0.063158, 
0.091935, 0.061702, 0.063924, 0.057407, 0.052234, 0.052711, 0.047317, 
0.042667, 0.043913, 0.033898, 0.035106, 0.26129, 0.28, 0.129956, 
0.306019, 0.190566, 0.117647, 0.158042, 0.106667, 0.142553, 0.142623, 
0.025571, 0.010624, 0.633824, 0.616667, 0.56338, 0.278652, 0.059597, 
0.013433, 0.088864, 0.305611, 0.314068, 0.298103, 0.398086, 0.491667, 
0.408537, 0.260582, 0.299312, 0.103511, 0.357472, 0.236501, 0.241833, 
0.276527, 0.353293, 0.4, 0.389776)), row.names = c(NA, -91L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Amazing!, Thank you very much! This is very helpful. Just a few questions to clarify. Where do the "start = list(m=0.1, b = 2, c=-0.05))" number come from? Just curious because I noticed the coeffients that are in table 3 equation 6 don't match the output of the model in the answer.

Comment: Looking at the table in the photo above is it possible they didn't use a non linear model? Maybe I am wrong, but table 3 equation number 6 has an R squared value which I take as meaning the model was linear? If it is indeed linear I am not sure what the original authors did.

Comment: The coefficients are close to the eq. 6.  If we put it into same form we have 0.07 + 0.35 exp(-0.054 RB).  Not sure why they got slightly different.  Could be a few reasons (e.g. perhaps they used a weighted fit, or excluded some outliers, etc.) If the exact method is not reported in the paper you may need to contact the authors if the small difference really matters.  The start values were just guesses that are close enough to converge on the solution.

Comment: Wouldn't necessarily read too much into the R2.  You are correct that it is not strictly an appropriate measure for non-linear models.  Nonetheless a lot of people report R2 for these in any case.

Comment: Thank you again @dww that clears up a lot. Sorry for my ignorance but I see where 0.07 and -0.054 come from but where does 0.35 in the equation come from if the coefficient b=-5.06265496?

Comment: algebra.  multiply out the brackets in your equation, and the 2nd term is `m * -b`.  i.e. 0.0685 * 5.06